# Python tkinter Entry widget status switch via Radio buttons

Tags: python, user-interface, radio-button, tkinter

a simple question (not so simple for a tkinter newby like me): I'm building a GUI and I want to have two radio buttons driving the status (enabled or disabled) of an Entry widget, into which the user will input data. When the first radio button is pressed, I want the Entry to be disabled; when the second radio button is pressed, I want the Entry to be disabled.

Here is my code:

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
frame = Frame(root)

#callbacks
def enableEntry():
    entry.configure(state=ENABLED)
    entry.update()

def disableEntry():
    entry.configure(state=DISABLED)
    entry.update()

#GUI widgets
entry = Entry(frame, width=80)
entry.pack(side='right')

var = StringVar()
disableEntryRadioButton = Radiobutton(frame, text="Disable", variable=var, value="0", command=disableEntry)
disableEntryRadioButton.pack(anchor=W)
enableEntryRadioButton = Radiobutton(frame, text="Enable", variable=var, value="1", command=enableEntry)
enableEntryRadioButton.pack(anchor=W)
```

My idea is to invoke the proper callbacks when each radio button is pressed. But I'm not pretty sure that it actually happens with the code I wrote,because when I select the radios the status of the Entry is not switched.

Where am I wrong with it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a few things wrong with your program, but the general structure is OK.

1. you aren't calling `root.mainloop()`. This is necessary for the event loop to service events such as button clicks, etc.
2. you use `ENABLED` and `DISABLED` but don't define or import those anywhere. Personally I prefer to use the string values `"normal"` and `"disabled"`.
3. you aren't packing your main `frame` widget

When I fix those three things your code works fine. Here's the working code:

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack()

#callbacks
def enableEntry():
    entry.configure(state="normal")
    entry.update()

def disableEntry():
    entry.configure(state="disabled")
    entry.update()

#GUI widgets
entry = Entry(frame, width=80)
entry.pack(side='right')

var = StringVar()
disableEntryRadioButton = Radiobutton(frame, text="Disable", variable=var, value="0", command=disableEntry)
disableEntryRadioButton.pack(anchor=W)
enableEntryRadioButton = Radiobutton(frame, text="Enable", variable=var, value="1", command=enableEntry)
enableEntryRadioButton.pack(anchor=W)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Bryan, apologize: I forgot to insert the `root.mainloop()` into my code excerpt (typo)