# Disable a spinbox with a radiobutton using grid

Tags: python, tkinter, checkbox, tk-toolkit

I try all the night for my problem so now I just ask the question here.

It's seems simple : how to disable a spinbox with a radiobutton?

I try to create 2 functions disable and enable and use the command in the command radiobutton but it does nothing. I try also to use the "parents" thing and it's not working. I try to just use a if but like always : not working.

Here ([Python tkinter Entry widget status switch via Radio buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6263226/python-tkinter-entry-widget-status-switch-via-radio-buttons)) I found some code who do what I want but with pack (I just change the entry by spinbox and it worked). However, it's a big program and I can't recode and relearn all with pack.

Anyone have an idea?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Then change the `pack()` to whatever layout function used in your program.

Comment: The standard way to disable any tk widget is `w.config(state=tk.DISABLED)`.  Why isn't that working for you?